# How to importing database from csv file in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

In my webapp I need put a page where the user can create a database from a csv fileupload. I try do this using a def how done in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/, but, dont work.

I guess the models is working sucessfully, because the others forms.

forms.py

```
class FileFieldForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = Colecao
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class ColecaoCSVCreate(CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'formulario/formulario_csv.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listar_colecao')

    def post(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES['sent_file']
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(f.read().decode('utf-8')))
                data = [line for line in reader]
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

formulario_csv.html

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="file" name="sent_file"/>
        
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Confirmar</button>

        {% endif %}
        <a href="/listar/colecao/">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cancelar</button>
        </a>
    </form>
```

When I upload csv a guet the error MultiValueDictKeyError at /cadastrar/csv/colecao/ 'sent_file'

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV file with pandas and transform each line to a dict:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your path file')
dict_df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

and later you can use the 'super' method to instance each dict element and save in the db:

first change your "**init**" method:

```
class FileFieldForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Colecao
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, my_dict, *args, **kwargs):
        for key in my_dict:
                setattr(self, key, my_dict[key])
        super(FileFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and now you can inicialize your object and save, like:

```
for my_dict in dict_df:
    element = FileFieldForm(my_dict)
    element.save()
```

Comment: when i use the "init" page is not work. this error appears "FileFieldForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'"

Comment: i change my answer, take a look

Comment: u also can create each object with its parameter